# How to make UIButton run online task?

Tags: php, mysql, database, swift, url

I am creating an app in swift 3.0 that uploads data to my MySQL database bridged by PHP then downloading it again to view in a UITableView.

I wanted to add a clear function that clears the table in phpMyAdmin through my app.

How would I do this?

I have the correct PHP code to do this. I just don't know how to make a UIButton in swift run a URL task such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make API which calls from UIButton, you have to pass data as request parameters that store on php MySQLdatabase. At response from same API get flag as stored successfully, then display that data in UITableView. Also you can fire command from php code to delete data from MySQLdatabase at any point.

Comment: Does it worked? if answer helped then you have to accept and close it.